# Form with has many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-validation, laravel-form

What is the better way to create a model with has many relationship?

For example:

I have two models:

- Client (id, name, ...)
- Contact (id, type, value, description)

A client has many Contacts.

Example of create client view: http://laravel.io/bin/mGXEE

Problems:

1. how to deal with validations?
2. if validation fails, going back and fill in the contact with the respective errors?

Comment: Can many contact belongstoMany client?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-2/episodes/4

Comment: @mazedlx, thx for the comment. that resolves the point 1, but not de second.

Comment: Did you take a look at the Laravel docs? There's a whole chapter dedicated to validation

Comment: of course. the problem here is the number of contacts isn't not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

With `php artisan make:request` you can make a request file that will validate your information. Take a look at the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation

Example:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:3|max:20',
            'lastname' => 'required|min:3|max:20',
            'adres' => 'required|min:3|max:20',
            'zip' => 'required|min:3|max:20',
            'city' => 'required|min:3|max:20'
        ];
    }
```

View:

```
 @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
      <p>{{ $error }}</p>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: the problem isn't that. is repopulate the contacts. plz see the view and the javascript